# Index for SDE XML data in Enterprise Geodatabase 10.6.1 in Oracle 19c

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, geodatabase-xml

We are in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. We are running Oracle 19c Enterprise Geodatabase.  The geoprocessing tools for managing domains are extremely slow.  Taking as much as 15 mins sometimes.  Is that due to lack of index on the XML LOB data?  What is the alternative for `sdexml` command for creating XML Index (XPath) on the SDE XML data stored in the Definition column on the gdb_items_vw (from sde_xml_doc1 table).  The older C and Java API that work with ArcSDE geodatabases had functions such as SE_xmltaginfo_create, SE_xmlindexinfo_add_tag, SE_xmlcolumninfo_set_index.  What are current alternative for that? https://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/concepts/xml/entities/xmlindex.htm#Creating

Ref : https://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/XML_columns_in_a_geodatabase_stored_in_Oracle/002n00000071000000/

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/system-tables-oracle.htm

https://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/concepts/xml/entities/xmlindex.htm

Comment: Referencing ancient documentation probably isn't going to be of much use.  There is no 'C' or Java API for geodatabase (and never had been, which is why the tools were deprecated -- too many people corrupting their geodatabase metadata).

Comment: provided ref to old documentation just as a reference.  What is option for poor performance on the XML data on the sde_xml_doc1 table ? any suggestion?

Comment: This is very nearly a pure RDBMS question.  Without traces of specific SQL commands and the optimizer's query plan, there is no way to tell if there *are* any options. It might take Tech Support a while to offer specific recommendations, but that will likely be faster than GIS SE could offer.

Comment: There isn't an arcxml datatype. It's an Oracle XML datatype.

Comment: my bad.  I meant ArcSDE XML type. This is defined in the DBTUNE parameter "XML_COLUMN_STORAGE" in oracle

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for!  ArcObjects supports SDE XML indexing under the GeoDatabase Namespace through Interfaces IXMLIndex, IXMLIndexEdit, IXMLIndexTags etc.

Comment: Those interfaces still only call native Oracle indexing functions.

Comment: well, I had no concerns on how they work under the hood.  My original concerns was just to find an alternative for the sdexml commands that add index to SDE XML data.  Looks like ArcObjects provides that.  I will post details in answer once I try this out.